# How to use Map filter in list by Java 8 lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Map is `Map<String, List<User>>` and List is `List<User>`. I want to use

```
Map<String,List<User>> newMap = oldMap.stream()
.filter(u ->userList.stream()
.filter(ul ->ul.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(u.getKey()).count()>0))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(u.getKey, u.getVaule()));
```

can't change to new `Map`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you intended to create a Stream of the entry Set of the input Map.

```
Map<String,List<User>> newMap =
    oldMap.entrySet().stream()
          .filter(u ->userList.stream().filter(ul ->ul.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(u.getKey())).count()>0)
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

This would create a `Map` that retains the entries of the original `Map` whose keys equal the name of at least one of the members of `userList` (ignoring case).

Comment: thx,and I change to Map<String,List<User>> is prompt cant not resolve symobl ' u '

Comment: @user2930390 Sorry about all the edits. I just tested it and found that some parentheses were in the wrong place, so the code didn't pass compilation. Now it does.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

- `Map` does not have a `stream()`: its entry set does, so you need to call `entrySet()` first.
- There are a couple of misplaced parentheses
- `Collectors.toMap` code is incorrect: you need to use the lambda `u -> u.getKey()` (or the method-reference `Map.Entry::getKey`) and not just the expression `u.getKey()`. Also, you mispelled `getValue()`.

This would be a corrected code:

```
Map<String, List<User>> newMap = 
        oldMap.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .filter(u -> userList.stream()
                                   .filter(ul ->ul.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(u.getKey())).count() > 0             
              ).collect(Collectors.toMap(u -> u.getKey(), u -> u.getValue()));
```

But a couple of notes here:

- You are filtering only to see if the count is greater than 0: instead you could just use [`anyMatch(predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-). This is a short-cuiting terminal operation that returns `true` if the predicate is `true` for at least one of the elements in the Stream. This has also the advantage that this operation might not process all the elements in the Stream (when filtering does)
- It is inefficient since you are traversing the `userList` every time you need to filter a Stream element. It would be better to use a `Set` which has O(1) lookup (so first you would convert your `userList` into a `userSet`, transforming the username in lower-case, and then you would search this set for a lower-case value username).

This would be a more performant code:

```
Set<String> userNameSet = userList.stream().map(u -> u.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)).collect(toSet());
Map<String,List<User>> newMap = 
        oldMap.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .filter(u -> userNameSet.contains(u.getKey().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)))
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(u -> u.getKey(), u -> u.getValue()));
```

Comment: I change to Map<String, List<User>>  is prompt cant not resolve symobl ' u '

Comment: @user2930390 You need to use a lambda inside `Collectors.toMap`: `u -> u.getKey()` and not `u.getKey()`